# Adding item to collection does not refresh activity designer

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

Am re-hosting my designer and have added a toolbox item which has a WorkflowItemsPresenter to render multiple child activity items. So my model item has a collection as:

```
    Sequence _innerSequence = new Sequence();
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Description("")]
    public Collection<Activity> Activities { get { return _innerSequence.Activities; } }
```

and the binding is

```
    <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Items="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Activities}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HintText="Drop activities here">
    <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="21"/>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
    </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter>
```

The binding works absolutely fine when the designer is loaded. Now i want to clear and add new items to this collection when some filter is updated on the designer. So in the set accessor of this filter property i call a method which does the following:

```
    private void RefreshApplication()
    {
        Activities.Clear();
        Activities.Add(new AddXYZApplication() { ApplicationName = "Test" });
    }
```

Though the collection gets updated the designer does not refresh. I know there is a way of doing this by writing some designer code-behind (i.e. updating the collection via the model item tree), but I would ideally like to have NO code-behind and expect it work like any other WPF application.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to devise a way (using multi-binding, using eventing etc) from sometime now.

Cheerio,
V

Comment: You've answered your own question. If you're binding to `ModelItem` you should do updates on it. And that's valid for all your workflow not only on your custom designer, if you want changes to reflect through out workflow designer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jota and apologies for the delay in response. I do understand that any changes have to be routed through the ModelItem  for the designer to refresh. However, just like when I set values to my InArgument activity properties and the designer refreshes without having to push the values via ModelItem, similarly when I add keys to my Collection activity property shouldn't the designer be notified. Am having to write designer code-behind to access the view ModelItem and add keys to the collection for designer to refresh. Though it works,  its more of a hack. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can alter your Activity directly and do a `WorkflowDesigner.Load` it each time you change something but that is the *hack way* and it won't be in sync with the ModelItem which is what you're really editing. I don't see why accessing ModelItem through code-behind could be an hack. It's the correct way to do it. Even on WPF-MVVM applications you've to write code-behind sometimes and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks @Jota ...its just that writing the code-behind is being a bit restrictive on the way my application is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer after my comment.

**When you're editing through WorkflowDesigner you haven't an `Activity` per se. What you have is a ModelItem**.

From the moment you load an activity to the designer, through `WorkflowDesigner.Load(activity)` you don't have an activity anymore, you just start editing a `ModelItem`.

You can access XAML through `WorkflowDesigner.Text` (after flush it) and do whatever you want with it. For example load it into an `ActivityBuilder` or `WorkflowService` but that is it.

Designers don't known, and never will, that activities have `Collection<Activities>`, `Collection<Variable>` or any other properties. They only know the `ModelItem` and the properties it has, period.

In resume: changes have to be made to `ModelItem` because it's what designers bind to.